# How can I target a specific link/click in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

http://jsfiddle.net/KevinOrin/KHHDT/

After clicking open 1 of the black bars/accordions (example: "Greenhouse Gases") I have a link "More/Less info" that is suppose to toggle more information. The problem is the click function is not on the "More/Less info" element but the entire "."happening-main-text" element. Clicking anywhere in the div activates the toggle and that shouldn't be. Any ideas how to modify this jQuery to target JUST the .readmore in that div?

```
    // More/Less Info Why Is Is Happening
jQuery('.readmore').closest(".happening-main-text").click(function()                
{                  
    jQuery(this).children(".divmore").toggle('slow');       
    return false;                                       
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
jQuery('.readmore').click(function() {                  
    jQuery(this).closest(".happening-main-text").children(".divmore").toggle('slow');       
    return false;                                       
});
```

What you did what precisely binding the event to the enclosing `".happening-main-text"` element.

[Demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/KHHDT/1/)

Comment: Don't use return false, just do e.preventDefault();

Comment: why shoudln't I use return false? Replace with "e.preventDefault();" ?

Comment: The page jumps/refreshes when I use prevent Default: http://jsfiddle.net/KevinOrin/KHHDT/3/

Comment: @ultraviol3tlux Can you explain your reasoning here ? What's wrong with `return false` ?

Comment: Return false can screw up other events that come after, it's a best practice to use preventDefault unless you specifically want to halt ALL javascript. To fix the scroll jumping, just force the scroll bar to show on the page: `html {overflow-y:scroll;}`

Comment: Hmm, not sure why that addition would stop the jumping. Can you refactor the code with all additions on updated jsfiddle?

Comment: What return false does:
event.preventDefault();
event.stopPropagation();
Stops callback execution and returns immediately when called.

Comment: Why make it so complicated ? `return false` is perfectly suited here, no need to change the CSS...